# How to integrate cakephp and magento?

Tags: cakephp, magento

I am trying to integrate magento with my cakephp application.
I have inserted this code,

```
<?php 

 require_once '../../../magento/app/Mage.php';

 umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
$productId = 5;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo "Name: ".$product->getName()."<br />";
echo "Type: ".$product->getStockItem()->getTypeId()."<br />";
echo "Price: ".$product->getFinalPrice()."<br />";
echo "Quantity available: ".(int)$product->getStockItem()->getQty()."<br />";
?>
```

and we have insert this code in ctp file
and try to run code, and getting this error:

```
 Constant DS already defined [C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php, line 27]
 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\vendorweb\lib\Cake\basics.php:501) in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 96
```

I have changed Mage.php like,

```
  if(!defined('DS')) {
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

}
```

but the other error still happens.

So can anyone please tell me how can it be done?
Can I run function __() both in cakehp and magento at the same time? Because according to my requirement, I can't change magento's single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If the error still happens it must be defined somewhere else too. Do a project wide search for `define('DS'` 
and see where else it is defined.

Comment: yes it is in index.php but that is not the solution, is I use the above code that error goes but the ` Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __()` comes. and not integration is done. so what the solution for displaying products from magento in cakephp?

Answer (score 0):

In file `'../../../magento/app/Mage.php'` you have to comment the line, probably the 27, with the following content:

`//define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`